# Eclipse Editor Plugin: Java inside XML file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, plugins, editor

I'm trying to develop an Eclipse plugin that enables syntax highlighting, content assistance, color formatting, etc. for Java code inside a specific tag in a XML file.

Using Eclipse PDE (and following [this tutorial](http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php)), I managed to extract the tags containing the Java code. I don't want to reimplement a Java Editor from scratch, can I use the [eclipse.jdt](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/ui) classes (such as JavaPartitionScanner, JavaColorManager, etc.)? If so, how? With another RuleBasedPartitionScanner? Or a simple RuleBasedScanner?

Or maybe there is an easy way to include the JavaEditor class inside another editor?

Any help? Or a starting point?

Thanks.

Comment: After looking at the [AspectJ Editor](http://git.eclipse.org/c/ajdt/org.eclipse.ajdt.git/tree/org.eclipse.ajdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/ajdt/internal/ui/editor), I see that their editor extends CompilationUnitEditor from the JDT. Maybe it's a better and easier  option ?